# Locally quadratic convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Show that the iteration method $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}x_n+\frac{a}{2x_n}, \ \ a>0$$ $n=1, 2, \ldots $ converges locally quadratic to $\sqrt{a}$.

Could you explain to me how we could show that?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

We have that $|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|=\frac1{2x_n}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2$.

To get local convergence we want that the starting point is near the root. Then this should hold for all approximations. So it must hold that $\left |x_n-\sqrt{a}\right |<\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$. Then we get: $$\left |x_n-\sqrt{a}\right |<\epsilon  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)}<\frac{1}{2x_n}<\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)}$$ So we get $$|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|  = \frac1{2x_n}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2 < \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2$$ If we choose for example $\epsilon=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$ we get $$|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|   < \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2 \text{ with } \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}>0$$
So the method converges locally and quadratic to $\sqrt{a}$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to assume $a\ne 0$, otherwise the convergence is linear ($\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\frac12$). From the iteration procedure
$$
x_{n+1}-\sqrt a = \frac1{2x_n}(x_n^2 + a - 2\sqrt a x_n) = \frac1{2x_n}(x_n-\sqrt a)^2 
$$
This is quadratic convergence if $(x_k)$ converges to $\sqrt a$.

Now, if the iteration is started at $x_1$ close to $\sqrt a$, i.e.,
$x_1 \in (\sqrt a-\delta,\sqrt a+\delta)$, then
$$
\frac1{2x_1}|x_1-\sqrt a| \le \frac\delta{2(\sqrt a-\delta)}
$$
This factor is equal to $\frac12$  if $\delta = \frac12\sqrt a$. Per induction one can show that $x_k \in  (\sqrt a-\delta,\sqrt a+\delta)$ for all $k$ and $x_k \to \sqrt a$. This is local convergence.

This iteration is nothing else than Newtons method applied to the equation $x^2=a$.

Comment: Ok! Could you explain to me in general what it means that the convergence is quadratic and what it means to be local? For the quadratic convergence do we have to show that $x_{n+1}-f(x)=L(x_n-f(x))^2$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar You may wish to read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1735193/272831). Local/global convergence means it will converge if you start (near the root)/(anywhere). Sometimes one may also speak of local convergence with how fast it converges, meaning it may initially start slow if you start far from the root.

Comment: As for the quadratic convergence, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt a}{(x_n-\sqrt a)^2}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{2x_n}$$ Do we consider that $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt{a}$ and so $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\sqrt{a}}$ ? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: So we get that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}-\sqrt a}{(x_n-\sqrt a)^2}=\frac1{2\sqrt{a}}>0 $$ right? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: How did you get $$\frac1{2x_1}|x_1-\sqrt a| \le \frac\delta{2(\sqrt a-\delta)}$$ ? @daw

Comment: We have that $|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|=\frac1{2x_n}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2$. 

To get local convergence we want that the starting point is near the root. Then this should hold for all approximations. So it must hold that $\left |x_n-\sqrt{a}\right |<\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Then we get: $$\left |x_n-\sqrt{a}\right |<\epsilon  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}+\epsilon)}<\frac{1}{2x_n}<\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)}$$ So we get $$|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|  = \frac1{2x_n}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2 < \frac{1}{2(\sqrt{a}-\epsilon)}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2$$ If we choose for example $\epsilon=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$ we get $$|x_{n+1}-\sqrt a|   < \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}|x_n-\sqrt a|^2 \text{ with } \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}>0$$ 
So the method converges locally and quadratic to $\sqrt{a}$. 

Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: @MaryStar Looks good to me.

Comment: So locally means that all approximations are near the root, i.e. $|x_n-\sqrt{a}|<\epsilon$ ? Is that trur for each $\epsilon$ ? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @MaryStar Only for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. Observe what happens if $x_0=-1$ and $a=1$ for example.

Comment: So is the part from "If we choose for example $\epsilon=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}$...." wrong? Or do we take the restiction at the beginning $0<\epsilon <1$ and not only $\epsilon>0$ ? @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: @MaryStar No, there is nothing wrong with taking $\epsilon=\sqrt a/2$. For $a=1$ you will see this $\epsilon$ is too tight to allow $x_0=-1$ for example.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)